# When using DI to inject a custom service into a Mediator Handler I encounter a base64 encoding issue

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-table-storage, mediator

I am building an azure table storage service. When I register it in the Startup.cs container everything works fine.
[image]

But when I start up and compile the application. Mediator returns an exception"

```
{"Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[BWAffinity.Application.MembersEmailed.MembersEmailed+Command,MediatR.Unit]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples."}
```

With an inner exception of:

```
InnerException = {"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."}
```

Here is the stacktrace just in case it is needed:
[image]

Here is where I try to inject the service into the handler:
[image]

My question is:

**What is causing this issue when I try to inject the service into the handler?**

Things I have tried:
I created two unit test that prove that it is working but the connection strings or "Keys" are passed directly into it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that in the container. I had the parameters in reverse. When doing dependency injection and passing in your values in the DI Container. Make sure your object parameters are input in the correct order.